# bootstrap 3 rc2 collapse navbar issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've just tried update to Bootstrap 3rc2 and am having issues recreating my navbar.
When the navbar is uncollapsed it does not list the items in it. I have copy and pasted the code in the documentation and still no success. I'm suspecting it has something to do with collapse.js or one of those dependencies.

I have a running example on my blog [morenoh149.github.io](http://morenoh149.github.io). The Bootstap docs [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it temporarily by linking to the same stylesheet file as used on getbootstrap.com

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Comment: very cool. now if only they updated the docs and I could center the navbar contents

Comment: Not sure if other's will have made this mistake but make sure you're not including any old bootstrap versions along with `Bootstrap 3 RC2` as this was my problem.

Comment: Exactly my prob, was going mad for ages trying to figure it out! Thanks for the mental prod